# iframe para banner responsive

Tags: html, css3

Buen día. Estoy teniendo problemas para hacer un banner responsive creado con `<iframe>`. Estoy usando el mismo método que uso para los vídeos, pero en este caso no me está funcionando.

**Código**

```css
.redes .embed-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.redes .embed-container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="redes">
  <div class="caja">
    <h2>Afiliados</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="embed-container">
    <iframe src="//rcm-eu.amazon-adsystem.com/e/cm?t=laxtore-21&o=30&p=12&l=ur1&category=videojuegos&banner=1RX48D6WZRXCY43X4EG2&f=ifr" width="300" height="250" scrolling="no" border="0" marginwidth="0" style="border:none;max-width:800px;max-height:600px;"
      frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

No consigo que el `iframe` se adapte a la resolución de manera dinámica.

Comment: quieres que tu iframe sea responsive?

Comment: Si es  lo que quiero conseguir.

Answer (score 1):

Los estilos no te funcionarán porque estás tratando con un documento embebido.  Si inspeccionas el banner, verás **que la imagen tiene un tamaño fijo** dentro de una tabla. Por lo que, aunque le des `100%` al banner **la imagen siempre tendrá el mismo tamaño**.

> La solución es **acceder al DOM del** `iframe`

Pero hay un problema con **acceder** al DOM del iframe por medio de `iframe.contentDocument`; porque es **muy probable** que obtengas una **restricción de seguridad** al ser dominios cruzados.

Una solución es obtener el HTML de la URL del banner en el servidor y enviarla al cliente. Una vez en el cliente, puedes convertir el string HTML en un documento como tal. Aquí ya todo es más sencillo porque puedes acceder directamente al DOM como siempre:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  let banners = document.querySelectorAll('.banner');

  [].forEach.call(banners, banner => {
    let url = btoa(banner.getAttribute('data-src'));

    fetch (`${url}?bannerURL=${url}`)
      .then(res => res.text())
      .then(parseHTML.bind(this, banner));
  });
});

function parseHTML (banner, html) {
  let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
  let table = doc.body.querySelector('table');
  banner.appendChild(table);
}
```

Finalmente, añades unos cuantos estilos para la tabla y la imagen:

```
.banner table {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.banner table img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

---

**Demo**

> **Nota**: El demo estará disponible solo un corto período de tiempo ya que estoy haciendo un redireccionamiento hacia localhost. Una vez que detenga ésto, actualizaré mi respuesta y eliminaré el demo.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let banners = document.querySelectorAll('.banner');

  [].forEach.call(banners, function (banner) {
    let url = btoa(banner.getAttribute('data-src'));

    fetch(`https://b4beb445.ngrok.io?bannerURL=${url}`)
      .then(res => res.text())
      .then(parseHTML.bind(this, banner));
  });
});

function parseHTML(banner, html) {
  let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
  let table = doc.body.querySelector('table');
  banner.appendChild(table);
}
```

```css
.redes .embed-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.redes .embed-container .banner {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 400px;
  max-width: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.banner table {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.banner table img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- solo para usar ES6 en navegadores viejos. No es necesario para que funcione. -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-promise/4.1.0/es6-promise.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fetch/2.0.3/fetch.min.js"></script>

<div class="redes">
  <div class="caja">
    <h2>Afiliados</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="embed-container">
    <div class="banner" data-src="//rcm-eu.amazon-adsystem.com/e/cm?t=laxtore-21&o=30&p=12&l=ur1&category=videojuegos&banner=1RX48D6WZRXCY43X4EG2&f=ifr">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

si utilizas flex, te ayudará a que sea responsive

```css
  
    #embed-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
    <div class="redes">
      <div class="caja">
        <h2>Afiliados</h2>
      </div>

      <div class="embed-container">
        <iframe src="//rcm-eu.amazon-adsystem.com/e/cm?t=laxtore-21&o=30&p=12&l=ur1&category=videojuegos&banner=1RX48D6WZRXCY43X4EG2&f=ifr" width="300" height="250" scrolling="no" border="0" marginwidth="0" style="border:none;max-width:800px;max-height:600px;"
          frameborder="0"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Me funciona entre medias. Para los banners laterales sin problema, el caso es que quiero introducir estos banners dentro de artículos, entre medias, para ello creo el div creando un `<h5>` y después ya dentro incluyo todo el `<iframe>`, sin embargo los estilos en este caso no me funcionan.